# How else can I execute this terminal command through Laravel-Livewire?

Tags: laravel

If I run what I dump in the terminal I get the file but running it via Laravel gives me nothing ... any thoughts?

```
$zipperPath = "cd " . storage_path('app/public/CMP/');
$zipper = "zip -r " . $zipFileName . " " . $cmp->company_code;

//dump($zipperPath);
//dd($zipper);

exec($zipperPath);
exec($zipper);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most certainly PHP can't find the `zip`-binary.
Give it a try with the full path to the binary: `/usr/bin/zip` (or what ever is correct on your system).

As `exec` doesn't give you much output and this is more than just a one-off script, I would suggest using the Symfony Process package to execute shell commands: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html